# maven compile without encoding some file

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, font-awesome, ico

I have a following problem. my project has some .ico files in resources like following[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwJgb.png)
and the favicon.ico looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQ0ck.png)
but when i use maven install or package the project i saw this :
"Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources."
maven is encoding my icon file too. so the picture is mixed like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZelnZ.png)
and my all font file eot,svg not works.
it's so wired anybody can help me? thanks!

Comment: it is a jar file,if copiled as war it will be ok

Comment: How did you configure this in your pom.xml file?

Comment: there is no special configure, just two plugins, spring-boot-maven-plugin,maven-jar-plugin

Comment: If you just use plugins, then resource filtering is disabled by default. However if you use the spring-boot parent pom (which you haven't mentioned), then resource filtering is on by default.

Answer (score 2):

i resoved it use maven-resources-plugin

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>ico</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>eot</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>svg</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>ttf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>woff</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>woff2</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the spring-boot-starter-parent as the parent pom, then resource filtering is turned on by default (it's off by default if you don't have a parent pom).

You can always turn it off explicitly:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

See: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html